# Free software to monitor serial port communication

Tags: windows-7, monitoring, windows-vista, serial

I'm looking for the Wireshark of Serial Port monitoring.
I'd prefer free/open-source software, but am willing to look
at commercial solutions if the price is reasonable.

It needs to be compatible with Windows Vista/7
and will be used to monitor all data traffic between two com ports on the same computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the [Free Serial Port Monitor](http://www.serial-port-monitor.com/free-serial-port-monitor-product-details.html), by HHD Software, to monitor communications with an old magnetic card reader.

They also have a [paid version](http://www.hhdsoftware.com/Products/home/serial-monitor.html) if you prefer.

Answer (score 4):

You could check if [Portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx) still works. I'm legacy-free here, so I can't test it myself ;).

Comment: It's a nice tool but not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: and it doesn't work in 64-bit environment…. the great plus that it is free...

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the everpresent Mark Russinovich has [crafted such a tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx), called Portmon.